# How can I avoid log files being garbled and to run background processes?

Tags: linux, tcl, expect

I was a complete newbie to expect and after all findings on google and expect book
I wrote [this](http://pastebin.com/LWFeqwRx) code but still it takes about 30-40 minutes to perform a task over a single ip address.

now I have come expect code inside for loop like this:

```
   foreach  host [ split $hosts "\;" ] {
      #blah blah blah

      #more code

      expect -re "$prompt"
      send -- "exit\r"
   }
```

now I need to run this for each host in background for parallel processing

how do I do this is it like:

```
   foreach  host [ split $hosts "\;" ] {
    {
      #blah blah blah

      #more code

      expect -re "$prompt"
      send -- "exit\r"
    } &
   }
```

wait

and how do I avoid log file getting garbled since each process may try to write at the same time to the same file.

EDIT: I have used a function called SendCommands to sendcommands puting buffers into log file like:

```
proc SendCommands { Commands } {
        global prompt log errlog
                foreach element [split $Commands ";"] {
                        expect {
                               -re $prompt
                                {send -- "$element\r"}
                               }
        set outcome "$expect_out(buffer)"
        puts "$log" "$outcome"
         }
}
```

Comment: `{...} &` does not work in Tcl

Comment: then how can i do this for each ip and avoid log file beaing garbled beacuse all the proceses would write to the file at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest technique by far is to split your code into two pieces in two files, one of which is the code that will interact a single host (and which takes the name of the host as a command line parameter in the `argv` variable), and the other of which will manage things across multiple hosts.

The crudest manager code might look like this (I'm guessing that writing and debugging the single host code won't be too hard for you):

```
foreach host [ split $hosts "\;" ] {
    exec expect perHostCode.tcl $host &
}
```

However, that runs into problems when the number of hosts goes up. In particular, the number of simultaneous runs of expect that you can do is limited by the number of virtual terminals that your OS installation has. This is typically *much smaller* than the number of processes or threads that you can run at once. You therefore need to limit the number that you do at a time if you've got lots of hosts.

Comment: Ahh; interrupt by family! Will fill in the rest later if you're interested. (What you've got will probably be fine up to 10–20 hosts.)

Comment: Thanks @Donal i don't have a big list of hosts 10 to 20 will work for me